# How to deploy a contract to parity using truffle?

Tags: truffle, parity

I get this when trying to deploy to parity -

> Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts
>
> Invalid JSON RPC response: "Provided Host header is not
>   whitelisted.\n"

I am new to using truffle with parity here is my truffle.js file -

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "0.0.0.0",
      port: 8540,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gas: 4712388
    }
  }
};
```

What could be the cause?

Here is my parity node -

```
nohup parity --config node0.toml --tracing=on --fat-db=on --pruning=archive  &

[parity]
chain = "demo-spec.json"
base_path = "/home/satoshimaca/blockchain/parity0"
[network]
port = 30300
[rpc]
port = 8540
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
[ui]
port = 8180
[websockets]
port = 8450
[account]
password = ["node.pwds"]
[mining]
engine_signer = "0x00bd138abd70e2f00903268f3db08f2d25677c9e"
reseal_on_txs = "none"
```

Comment: by default, rpc host address would be 127.0.0.1, which you can change with --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0, OR you can change truffle.js file and put host: "127.0.0.1"

Comment: I changed that already but then it just was hanging, that sounds like a mining issue but I am using PoA so I would not expect any mining.

Answer (score 0):

Parity runs on localhost, change the `host` in your truffle configuration file to `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0` and try again.